# Getting 20-30 emails per day replies for emails I didn't send

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I'm getting like 20-30 emails per day on my gmail account that I tied to my own domain name.

Most of the emails are linkedin emails, or out of office emails that are coming back.

Say my domain is `example.com`

The email being used is like  `rmpslw01@example.com`

And account I didn't create, nor does the account even exist.

Is this a problem with gmail?

Comment: No, it's a problem with the internet.  It's easy to send email posing as if it's being sent from someone else's (or a made up) email address.  Spammers do it constantly.

Comment: Google "email backscatter" for details

Comment: @BBlake I would have thought gmail would have figured it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google apps has "Catch-all address" which routes all unknown addresses to that. Have you turned it on?

Also might be that spammers use random To: address and your address is just Bcc'd which doesn't show up.

Comment: I'm not sure, that is what I thought it might be but I dont' see a catch all address. I'll look into that.